# Loop inside loop for .Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to retrieve all User_id's next after my entered User_id referencing each other from the table by Reference_id, the code below gives the exact result but it retrieves all User_id's from "2001 to 2005".

I want if i enter the "2002" as User_id from a textbox then it must retrieve from "2003 - 2005"

Table_xyz column User_id have value= 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005
Table_xyz column Reference_id have value= 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004

```
var gCmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT User_id FROM Table_xyz", nCon);
SqlDataAdapter Sda = new SqlDataAdapter(gCmd);
DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
Sda.Fill(Dt);

for (int i = 0; i < Dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string referenceid = Dt.Rows[i]["User_id"].ToString();

    var gCmd1 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT User_id FROM Table_xyz 
    WHERE Reference_id = '" + referenceid + "'", nCon);

    SqlDataAdapter Sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(gCmd1);
    DataTable Dt1 = new DataTable();
    Sda1.Fill(Dt1);

    Response.Write(referenceid);
}
```

I tried adding "SELECT User_id FROM Table_xyz WHERE User_id = '2001'" to the first command but it returns only a single value where User_id matched "2001"

Comment: What issue you are facing with this code,? Did you debug to figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Yes there is no error, but i think i am not understanding the logic,
It returns only first value not for rest

Comment: it is returning just one value becase the loop is running just one time.  This array ``var array = list.ToArray();`` has just one value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest solution. But consider refactoring your code or thinking on another approach, this is not perfomatic. Also consider using parameters on you sql command.

```
            string initialId = Dt.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString();
            do
            {
                string dCmd = "SELECT ID FROM TableA WHERE Reference_ID = '" + initialId + "'";
                SqlDataAdapter dSda = new SqlDataAdapter();
                dSda.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(dCmd, nCon);
                DataTable dDt = new DataTable();

                dSda.Fill(dDt);

                for (int i = 0; i < dDt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    initialId = dDt.Rows[i]["ID"];
                    Response.Write(dDt.Rows[i]["ID"]);
                }
            }
            while(dDt.Rows.Count > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution, in first you can get all distinct `Refrence_ID` and based on that you can loop to get `IDs`

```
var gCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myCon"].ConnectionString;
using (var nCon = new SqlConnection(gCon))
{
    try
    {
        nCon.Open();
        String cmd = "SELECT DISTINCT Refrence_ID FROM TableA";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd, nCon);
        DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(Dt);

        for (int count = 0; count < Dt.Rows.Count(); count++)
        {
            string dCmd = "SELECT ID FROM TableA WHERE Reference_ID = '" + dt.Rows[count]["Refrence_ID"] + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter dSda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dSda.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(dCmd, nCon);
            DataTable dDt = new DataTable();
            dSda.Fill(dDt);

            for (int i = 0; i < dDt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Response.Write(dDt.Rows[i]["Distributor_ID"]);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Response.Write(e.ToString());
    }
    finally { nCon.Close(); }
}
```

Comment: Actually it's the same, so please add a Reference id in the first command where connection is opened then see...

String cmd = "SELECT DISTINCT Refrence_ID FROM TableA";

I want to add WHERE Reference_ID = '0' (Something like this)

String cmd = "SELECT DISTINCT Refrence_ID FROM TableA WHERE Reference_ID = '0'";

It will give 1 value, instead i wanted to get entire ID's fetching each other by Reference_Id

Comment: Have you tried this solution in your application? as this will giev you all IDs for all  Refrence_IDs one by one in loop. Please elaborate your question more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all of you my friends for the effort to help me but unfortunately that didn't solved the main issue.

After lot's of research for the same i got my answer at "Recursive command", so finally my code is below

```
        string value = "2723022"; // <== any reference id from Reference_id column
        String gCmd = "SELECT DISTINCT Reference_id FROM myTable WHERE User_id >'" + value + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter Sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        Sda.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(gCmd, nCon);
        DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
        Sda.Fill(Dt);

        for (int count = 0; count < Dt.Rows.Count; count++)
        {
            string dCmd = "SELECT User_id FROM dEmo_aCcounts WHERE Reference_id = '" + Dt.Rows[count]["Reference_id"] + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter dSda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dSda.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(dCmd, nCon);
            DataTable dDt = new DataTable();
            dSda.Fill(dDt);

            for (int i = 0; i < dDt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Response.Write(dDt.Rows[i]["User_id"]);
            }
        }
```